# Why I cannot open NVENC projects in VS2010?

Tags: nvidia, video-encoding, gpu

I've downloaded [NVENC SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk).
When I open `samples_vs2008.sln` - all projects are loaded in the solution and `nvEncoder` is working.

When I open `samples_vs2010.sln`:

1. only `nvEncoder` project is loaded and other 3 projects (`cudaDecodeD3D9`, `cudaDecodeGL`, `cudaEncode`) fail to load.
2. For each failed project I get this error:
   **...\cudaDecodeD3D9_vs2010.vcxproj : error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 5.5.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.**
3. Even if I still decide to run the only loaded project (`nvEncoder`) I get error
    **Unable to start program nvEncoder.exe. The system cannot find the file specified.**
   Though nvEncoder.exe does exist!

Do you have any idea what could be the problem? Why it wants `CUDA 5.5.props` for VS2010 and 5.0 for VS2008?

Answer (score 0):

The NVIDIA VIDEO CODEC SDK apparently depends on the NVCUVID CUDA API. You should download and install the GPU Computing SDK (https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-computing-sdk).

Comment: The fact that VS2008 does open all projects and it works means that I did install NVCUVID CUDA API:) This is not the problem